# Thumbnail of Uploaded Documented in PHP

Tags: php, linux, laravel, powerpoint, doc

I want to generate thumbnail (first page) of following file formats:

- PDF
- DOC/DOCX [MS OFFICE]
- PPT/PPTX [MS OFFICE]

For PDF I got many libraries and ImageMagick & Ghost Script did for me.

But for other formats i.e. ppt, pptx, doc and docx. I can't find any lead to solution.

Preferred language is PHP but option is open for every language that can run on linux. Thanks alot.

Comment: please provide some more details. what you have tried so far.

Comment: thanks for the response @AdnanMumtaz.. i have used imagick to generate thumbnail of PDF file. but it doesn't give us permission to generate  thumbnail of DOC, DOCX, PPT or PPTX..

Comment: You have to use different libraries for different type of docs.

Comment: Yes I have searched for other libraries. but i can't find any lead to solution. please help me out if you have any solution

Comment: you can use PHPOffice

Comment: PHPOffice is not working for this case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176992/discussion-between-nouman-saleem-and-adnan-mumtaz).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service like [Post2Preview](https://post2preview.com). It can generate thumbnails and OCR for hundreds of file types and doesn't require any third party libraries. Just a simple POST request. Disclaimer: I work for Post2Preview

Comment: thanks for reply.. can you please tell me how to use

Comment: Sure, basically first you create an "app" on the dashboard with a key and secret for the API. Then send the URL to your file in an HTTP POST request to the endpoint on the docs page. It'll process your file and then send a callback to the URL you specified in your "app" on the dashboard with the URLs to the thumbnails and OCR content. Reach out to us if you need anymore help: support@post2preview.com